# Composition of two functions discontinuous at a point

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm asked to either prove or disprove the following statement:

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$.
If $f$ is discontinuous at $x=x_0$ and $g$ is discontinuous at $f(x_0)$, then $g \circ f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$.

I can't think of any obvious counterexamples, however I am not sure about how I would go about proving it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed false. Take, for instance, $x_0=0$,$$g(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x\geqslant 0\\1&\text{ if }x<0\end{cases}\text{ and }f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x=\frac1n\text{ for some }n\in\mathbb N\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$They are both discontinuous at $0(=f(0))$, but $g\circ f$ is the null function.